# '2.1.1-PREVIEW' is not a valid version string. Parameter name: version

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, nuget-package, ext.net

I try to install Ext.NET MVC but I got this error

> '2.1.1-PREVIEW' is not a valid version string.
>   Parameter name: version

Does anyone know the solution of this problem ?

Comment: Is the same issue discussed [here](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?28056)?

Answer (score 1):

Please first install 'Transformer.NET (≥ 2.1.1)' and  then try to install ext.net on nuget.
It's giving error because Transformer.Net is not installed.